# How to check whether field is Updateable or not on Visual Force page itself

Tags: apex, class

[image]

[image]

Here i am trying to check whether the case field is editable or not and if it is editable i want to show a text box there, is there any way to check it on Visual Force page itself. can anyone please help me out.

VF Page-

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!waAccList}" var="eachRecord" id="table123"> 

  <apex:column headerValue="Action">
    <apex:commandLink value="Remove" style="color:red" action="{!removeRowFromAccList}"  rerender="CaseHead" immediate="true" >
         <apex:param value="{!eachRecord.position}" name="rowToRemove" assignTo="{!rowToRemove}"/>
     </apex:commandLink>

  </apex:column>
  <apex:column headerValue="S.No." id="position">
                       <apex:outputText value="{!eachRecord.position}"/> 
   </apex:column>


   <apex:column headerValue="Case Field">
                        <apex:selectList multiselect="false"  size="1" title="select case Field" value="{!eachRecord.CaseFieldSelected}" > 

                <apex:selectOptions value="{!eachRecord.caseFieldOptions}" />
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  reRender="table123" />
            </apex:selectList><p/>

   </apex:column>
   <apex:column headerValue="Condition">
                        <apex:selectList multiselect="false"  size="1" title="select case Field"  > 

                <apex:selectOptions value="{!eachRecord.operatorOptions}" />
            </apex:selectList><p/>
   </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Case Name" id="demo">
                       <apex:outputText value="{!eachRecord.caseFieldSelected}"/> 
   </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Value">
                      <apex:inputField value="{!eachRecord.record[eachRecord.caseFieldSelected]}" rendered="{!!eachRecord.isUpdateable}"/> 
                       <apex:inputText value="{!eachRecord.searchstring}" rendered="{!eachRecord.isUpdateable}"/>
   </apex:column>


</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

```
Controller--


   public with sharing class ConditionalPageExtension{

        public PageReference SaveMultipleCases() {
        system.debug('controller save method is calling-->');
         ConditionalPageExtensionhelper.save(waAccList);
        return null;
        }


     public List<WrapperpaCaseList> waAccList {get;set;}
     public Integer rowToRemove {get;set;}

     public ConditionalPageExtension(){
      waAccList = new List<WrapperpaCaseList>();
      addNewRowToAccList();
     }
     public void removeRowFromAccList(){
      waAccList = ConditionalPageExtensionhelper.removeRowToCaseList(rowToRemove, waAccList);
      integer i=1;
      for(WrapperpaCaseList caseobj1 :waAccList ){
          caseobj1.position=i;
          i++;
      }

     }

     public void addNewRowToAccList(){
         waAccList = ConditionalPageExtensionhelper.addNewRowToAccList(waAccList);
        }



     public class WrapperpaCaseList{
            public Integer index {get;set;}
            public Case record {get;set;}
            Public list<selectoption>caseFieldOptions{get;set;}
            Public list<selectoption>operatorOptions{get;set;}
            Public String operatorSelected{get;set;}
            Public String caseFieldSelected{get;set;}
            Public Integer position{get;set;}
            Public boolean isUpdateable{get;set;}
            public String searchstring {get;set;}

               public WrapperpaCaseList(){
                  isUpdateable = false;
               }

       } 
    }
```

ConditionalPageExtensionhelper--

```
public class ConditionalPageExtensionhelper {

    public static List<ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList> addNewRowToAccList(List<ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList> waAccObjList){
        ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList newRecord = new ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList();
        Case newCaseRecord = new Case();  

       newRecord.record = newCaseRecord;
        newRecord.index = waAccObjList.size();
        newRecord.operatorOptions= new list<selectoption>();
        newRecord.operatorOptions.add(new Selectoption('=','='));
        newRecord.operatorOptions.add(new Selectoption('!=','!='));
        newRecord.caseFieldOptions = new list<selectoption>();
        Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap= Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        integer i=1;
        for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()){ 
            if (i==1){
                newRecord.caseFieldSelected =string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getname());
                i++;
            }
           newRecord.caseFieldOptions.add(new selectOption(string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getname()),string.valueof(sfield.getDescribe().getlabel())));

        }
        newRecord.position = waAccObjList.size()+1;
        waAccObjList.add(newRecord);
        return waAccObjList;
    }


     public static List<ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList> removeRowToCaseList(Integer rowToRemove, List<ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList> waCaseList){
        rowToRemove = rowToRemove-1;
        waCaseList.remove(rowToRemove);
        integer i=1;
       // system.debug('----->'+waCaseList);

        return waCaseList;
    }

    public static void save(List<ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList> waAccList) {
        system.debug('==waAccList==>'+waAccList.size());
        List<Case> CaseRecordsToBeInserted = new List<Case>();
        if(waAccList !=null && !waAccList.isEmpty()){
            for(ConditionalPageExtension.WrapperpaCaseList eachRecord : waAccList ){
      //          Case accTemp = eachRecord.record;
        //        CaseRecordsToBeInserted.add(accTemp);

            }
            system.debug('==CaseRecordsToBeInserted==>'+CaseRecordsToBeInserted.size());
            insert CaseRecordsToBeInserted;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ratan Are You There ??  @sfdcweb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following syntax in VF page to check if a field is updateable:

```
"{!$ObjectType.<ObjectName>.fields.<Field Name>.Updateable}"
```

the above exp will return true if it is updatable and false otherwise.